# how to deal with file of numbers c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have file contain numbers like these 
123.4  23.7  89.2  ...
45.8
...

8 columns and 1024 rows, and I want to read this file row by row and put each row in array of double to get the minimum number from this row and put this minimum number in array with size 1024 .

I tried this code in c# ...

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        double[] row = new double[8];
        double[] minimum = new double[1024];
        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

        for (int k = 0; k < 1024; k++)
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null )
            {

                string[] numbers = new string[8];
                int numCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (line[i] != ' ')
                    {
                        numbers[numCount] = "";
                        while (line[i] != ' ')
                        {
                            numbers[numCount] += line[i];
                            i++;

                        }
                        numCount++;

                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = Convert.ToDouble(numbers[i]);
                }

                double min = row[0];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (row[j] <= min)
                        min = row[j];

                }
                minimum[k] = min;

            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The array contain:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(minimum[i]);

           file.Close();


        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: `string.Split()` will eliminate about 80% of this code.

Comment: Take a look at string.split()

Comment: `use Linq` to not only read the File all at once but within the process of reading the file use the .`Split()` method to have the List<int> or String, or double, quickly populated `Split on " "` if the space is the  `Delimiter`

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods that can simplify your code - [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) and LINQ Select. Resulting code could look similar to:

```
var listOfArraysOfDouble = File.ReadLines(fileName)
    .Select(row => 
         row.Split((string[]) null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(columnValue => double.Parse(columnValue))
           .ToArray()
     );
```